# Regex to group into 3 groups

Tags: regex

I have the following text below that I want to group into 3 groups.

```
"ax (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"by master1 (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"chef (1,507) 923 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"children (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"chris test (1) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Noncritical",
"_Regression (8) 315 Critical Issues | 0 Noncriticals"
```

I want the formatted text to look like below

```
ax, 0, 0
by master, 0, 0
chef, 923, 0
children, 0, 0
chris test 0, 0
_Regression 315, 0
```

Is this possible using regex?

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your text I think this regex should do

```
([_a-zA-Z0-9 ]+) \([0-9,]+\) ([0-9,]+) Critical Issues \| ([0-9,]+) Non-?criticals?
```

You then need to use [bracket-matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to pull out the three values from each line that you want and format them appropriately.

Basically you put part of the regular expression between parentheses `(`, `)` which marks that part of the pattern as *grouped* allowing you identify the part of the input string that the pattern inside the parentheses matches.

## A simple example:

Input strings:

```
"456-abc-123",
"387-zxf-345",
"830-fft-492"
```

Regex:

```
[0-9]+-([a-z]+)-[0-9]+
```

With this pattern we could choose to pull out the text matched by `([a-z]+)` for each string which would give us:

```
abc
zxf
fft
```

If you can tell the language that you want to use we'll be able to give a code solution.

---

## A solution in python:

```
import re

text = ["ax (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"by master1 (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"chef (1,507) 923 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"children (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"chris test (1) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Noncritical",
"_Regression (8) 315 Critical Issues | 0 Noncriticals"]

for entry in text:
    m = re.search(r'([_a-zA-Z0-9 ]+) \([0-9,]+\) ([0-9,]+) Critical Issues \| ([0-9,]+) Non-?criticals?', entry)
    print "%s, %s, %s" % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))
```

Outputs:

```
ax, 0, 0
by master1, 0, 0
chef, 923, 0
children, 0, 0
chris test, 0, 0
_Regression, 315, 0
```

---

## A solution in ruby:

```
text = ["ax (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"by master1 (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"chef (1,507) 923 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"children (0) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Non-critical",
"chris test (1) 0 Critical Issues | 0 Noncritical",
"_Regression (8) 315 Critical Issues | 0 Noncriticals"]

for entry in text
    m = /([_a-zA-Z0-9 ]+) \([0-9,]+\) ([0-9,]+) Critical Issues \| ([0-9,]+) Non-?criticals?/.match(entry)
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", m[1], m[2], m[3])
end
```

Also outputs:

```
ax, 0, 0
by master1, 0, 0
chef, 923, 0
children, 0, 0
chris test, 0, 0
_Regression, 315, 0
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I dont have enough rep to upvote it :(